# Conda py2 environment uses pip3 instead of pip

Tags: python, environment-variables, conda

I've downloaded Miniconda3 and I've activated the Python2.7 environment. I've looked in the bin directory and it contains pip. I've tried to `pip install numpy`, but it redirects to /usr/local/bin/pip3 and I get the error that the pip package is not found. Why is it prioritizing Python 3.8? The only thing I can think of is changing my $PATH variable to only include `/miniconda3/envs/py2/bin`. I'd appreciate any suggestions - thanks!

Comment: seems like you haven't actually activated the environment.

Comment: @gshpychka - I ran `conda create --name py2 python=2.7` and I'm using `conda activate py2` and I see `(py2) username-MBP ~ %`. Maybe anaconda and miniconda operate differently? Although I didn't see anything special in the docs.

Comment: Right - it's a conda environment, so you would use conda to install packages, not pip. If you must use pip, you can do `python -m pip`

Comment: @gshpychka - thanks, I didn't know that command. It worked!

Comment: Using pip with conda is not a very good idea, though.

Comment: Do you maybe have an alias for `pip`? Can you type `type pip` in your terminal?